# How not to change the position when an item from ListView is deleted

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a ListView and every time I delete an item the position of the other items is changing. Any ideas on how to stop it or get the data as in a "Row position"?

Comment: Use RecyclerVIew.

Answer (score 0):

Then in your getView() method set the tag for that button like,

```
button.setTag(position)
```

and then in your button click listener,

```
 int pos = view.getTag();
list.remove(pos);
```

finally you need two refresh the list view in click listener itself.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Try this out.

Comment: Thats my bad. I wrongly added it as an answer :) removed it. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it helps you? Or please add some more descriptions to the question.

Comment: Could you please add more description? some code snippet which you are trying now will give some idea about what's going wrong.

Comment: I found the solution. I just get the id from the database based on a search and the problem was solved. Thanks anyway!